# How to compare time format and time stamp?

Tags: bash, datetime, comparison

I have time format like `[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]` and time stamp like `[2009/05/11 07:30:00]`. What I need is How to compare these two values. Possible is that time stamp is not similar like time format, for example `[%Y-%m%d %H:%M]`. This is wrong. 
Some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **[verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308911/how-to-compare-time-format-and-time-stamp/23309235#comment35684818_23309014)** that a date string is in a specific format, you can coerce the date into the format you want and verify that the string is the same as you started with:

```
$ format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
$ invalid_date='2009/05/11 07:30'
$ [ "$(date --date="$invalid_date" +"$format")" = "$invalid_date" ]
$ echo "$?"
1
$ valid_date='2009/05/11 07:30:00'
$ [ "$(date --date="$valid_date" +"$format")" = "$valid_date" ]
$ echo "$?"
0
```

This will only work for date strings which are `date` compatible (you can't specify the input formatting directly in `date`).

Comment: It is not valid because at format is `-` and date has `/` between year, month, day. After repair It is ok. Thanks @l0b0

Answer (score 2):

If the dates are not necessarily in the same format, one simple way is to convert them to Unix timestamps:

```
$ date --date="2009/05/11 07:30:00" +%s
1242023400
$ date --date="2009/05/11 07:30" +%s
1242023400
```

This will give you an integer value which you can easily compare using:

```
if [ "$(date --date="$my_date" +%s)" -gt "$(date --date="$my_other_date" +%s)" ]
```

`date` understands many common date formats without having to munge the input first.

Comment: But [2009/05/11 07:30:00] is not same like [%Y-%m%d %H:%M]. Means the return code is 1, not same equals wrong.

Comment: Using `date` 8.22 from GNU coreutils the exit code is 0 in both cases, and they give the same result. Are you using a different `date`?

Comment: Yes, I know. But important for me is the TIME FORMAT. In my script, if it is not same, return 1. If it is same return 0.
Example:
if [[ "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]" -eq "[2009/05/11 07:30:00]" ]] && return 0 || return 1

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are in the same format, and that format is 4-digit year followed by month, date, hour, minute, and second, but some are truncated at the end, you can fill in the suffix and compare those dates as strings:

```
$ rpad_date() {
    case ${#1} in
        4)
            format='%s/01/01 00:00:00'
            ;;
        7)
            format='%s/01 00:00:00'
            ;;
        10)
            format='%s 00:00:00'
            ;;
        13)
            format='%s:00:00'
            ;;
        16)
            format='%s:00'
            ;;
        19)
            format='%s'
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown format: $1" >&2
            return 1
     esac
     printf "$format" "$1"
}
$ rpad_date "2004"
2004/01/01 00:00:00
```